What is the overhead if IIS logs is enabled for Windows event viewer?
We have an .aspx Asp.Net Web Forms C# application on IIS 10 on Windows Server 2022.
Recently an issue occurred where the application pool assigned to the application stopped without a trace to identify the cause.
I came across IIS Logging in Windows event viewer, Applications And Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> IIS-Logging -> Logs but we are concerned about whether we should enable it on a shared server where other applications are also running.
Will it cause overhead such as log file size growing or will the performance of the other sites will be degraded if we enable IIS Logging in event viewer?

Not sure which IIS-Logging you are referring to, and who suggested that. Please edit the question to explain more about it. For such problems, IIS crash dumps are more straight forward, but of course require more experience to configure and analyze.

@LexLi the path in event viewer is:- Applications And Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> IIS-Logging -> Logs

Why don't you enable it temporarily and observe the impact it has? Possibly enable it during a time when the system is less busy?
